# Error In Blazor When Getting Stream of ML NET Model zip file

Tags: c#, blazor, ml.net, blazor-webassembly, ml.net-model-builder

I have a problem with Blazor.
I tried to do what's said in the documentation about loading existing model from remote source.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/save-load-machine-learning-models-ml-net)

This is what I came up with:

```
@page "/analyzer"
@inject HttpClient _client
<h1>Analyzer</h1>

<input class="form-control" @bind:event="oninput" @bind="InputText"/>

@if (InputText != null)
{
    <h1>@InputText</h1>
}

@code {
    private string _inputText, mlPrediction;
    DataViewSchema modelSchema;
    MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();
    public string InputText
    {
        get
        {
            return _inputText;
        }
        set
        {
            _inputText = value;
            GetPrediction();
        }
    }
    private PredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput> _predictionEngine;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Stream modelFile = await _client.GetStreamAsync("<MODEL.ZIP ENDPOINT>");
        ITransformer trainedModel = mlContext.Model.Load(modelFile, out modelSchema);
        _predictionEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput>(trainedModel);
    }
    private void GetPrediction()
    {
        ModelInput mlInput = new ModelInput();
        mlInput.Sentiment = InputText;
        ModelOutput mlOutput = _predictionEngine.Predict(mlInput);
        mlPrediction = mlOutput.Prediction;
    }
}
```

When I initialize the page, there was an error, and the only thing I understood is there is an error in line 32,

```
_predictionEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput>(trainedModel);
```

I could not find anyone with the same problem.
Here's the error code:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load the file 'Microsoft.ML.Transforms, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) <0x296c470 + 0x000ce> in <filename unknown>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) <0x296c470 + 0x000ce> in <filename unknown>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) <0x296c470 + 0x000ce> in <filename unknown>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) <0x296c470 + 0x000f6> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) <0x296bd98 + 0x00014> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.ComponentCatalog+LoadableClassInfo.CreateInstanceCore (System.Object[] ctorArgs) <0x545e428 + 0x000dc> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.ComponentCatalog+LoadableClassInfo.CreateInstance (Microsoft.ML.Runtime.IHostEnvironment env, System.Object args, System.Object[] extra) <0x545e070 + 0x000c4> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.ComponentCatalog.TryCreateInstance[TRes] (Microsoft.ML.Runtime.IHostEnvironment env, System.Type signatureType, TRes& result, System.String name, System.String options, System.Object[] extra) <0x545d848 + 0x001c8> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.ComponentCatalog.TryCreateInstance[TRes,TSig] (Microsoft.ML.Runtime.IHostEnvironment env, TRes& result, System.String name, System.String options, System.Object[] extra) <0x545d488 + 0x00018> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.TryLoadModelCore[TRes,TSig] (Microsoft.ML.Runtime.IHostEnvironment env, TRes& result, System.Object[] extra) <0x5365f30 + 0x00068> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.TryLoadModel[TRes,TSig] (Microsoft.ML.Runtime.IHostEnvironment env, TRes& result, Microsoft.ML.RepositoryReader rep, Microsoft.ML.Repository+Entry ent, System.String dir, System.Object[] extra) <0x535cb38 + 0x00068> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.LoadModel[TRes,TSig] (Microsoft.ML.Runtime.IHostEnvironment env, TRes& result, Microsoft.ML.RepositoryReader rep, Microsoft.ML.Repository+Entry ent, System.String dir, System.Object[] extra) <0x535c980 + 0x00038> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.LoadModelOrNull[TRes,TSig] (Microsoft.ML.Runtime.IHostEnvironment env, TRes& result, Microsoft.ML.RepositoryReader rep, System.String dir, System.Object[] extra) <0x5351628 + 0x00064> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.LoadModel[TRes,TSig] (Microsoft.ML.Runtime.IHostEnvironment env, TRes& result, Microsoft.ML.RepositoryReader rep, System.String dir, System.Object[] extra) <0x5351438 + 0x00034> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.ML.ModelOperationsCatalog.Load (System.IO.Stream stream, Microsoft.ML.DataViewSchema& inputSchema) <0x5243828 + 0x000a0> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Deployments.Pages.SentimentAnalyzer2.OnInitializedAsync () [0x00096] in <PROJECTDIRECTORY>\Pages\SentimentAnalyzer2.razor:32 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync () <0x2ecb9b0 + 0x0013a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask (System.Threading.Tasks.Task taskToHandle) <0x31219d8 + 0x000b6> in <filename unknown>:0
```

I really have no idea what to do.

I used:

- ASP.NET Core 3.1
- ML.NET 1.5
- .NET Standard 2.1

I found someone who seemed to have a success on similar type of project and our programs are structurally the same: https://www.luisquintanilla.me/2020/03/01/deploy-machine-learning-mlnet-models-blazor-webassembly

I hosted my ML Model both on DigitalOcean and in the wwwroot but it has the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of .NET 5 RC1 (.NET 5 or .NET 6), you can now host ML.NET machine learning models in-memory in a client-side Blazor WASM application.

My link of Blazor Server & WASM demos with ML.NET:
https://github.com/bartczernicki/Blazor-MachineIntelligence

Answer (score 1):

If this is a Blazor WASM application then unfortunately ML NET is incompatible. ML NET requires a x86 which doesn't exist in WebAssembly. Therefore you must process your ML Model on the server and send the results to the client over HTTP.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but ML.NET requires x64. There could be other reasons it's not compatible, though.

Comment: Well, that's sad. Thanks anyway. Would you recommend Blazor Server or a Hosted WASM for ML.NET?

Comment: You can follow Seth's blog there's some ML NET examples there. https://www.sethjuarez.com/2020/09/10/cors-and-mixed-content-with-azure-functions/?s=09

Comment: Or you can use Blazor server instead of Wasm. https://github.com/EdCharbeneau/BlazePort